# Readline function does not print the heders of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, readline

#Readline function does not print the heders of a CSV file

[The CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNK20.png)

#Code

```
 path_TI = 'tips.csv'

 with open(path_TI) as f:

     for i in f:

         print(f.readline())
```

#Output

16.99,1.01,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,2

21.01,3.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3

24.59,3.61,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,4

8.77,2.0,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading from `f` twice, both when calling `f.readline()` and in the for loop `for i in f`

This causes the program to first read the first line of the file (and setting the variable i to the value) and then printing the next line it reads.

Your code should probably look like this instead:

```
for i in f:
    print(i)
```